# bzr revert only a hunk? (bzr version of "git checkout --patch")

Tags: git, bazaar

I deleted about a paragraph in code, then did `bzr commit -m "temp commit"` and what to *only* get that single paragraph back. Is there a way to do this in bazaar?

Answer (score 1):

Use `bzr shelve --destroy` to shelve the changes (a-la `git stash`) and kill them.